# Pagination in PHP and an Infinite Loop

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I am trying to convert an [old vbscript function](http://polancophp.com/projects/keystone/old_vb_function.txt) into a php function and run I run it, it appears to be stuck in a infinite loop.  Here is the script:

```
<?php
function pagination($str,$max_pg){
    $pg = (int)$str;
    $max_pg = (int)$max_pg;
    if($max_pg <= 1){
        exit();
    }

    $pstrout = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">\r';
    $pstrout .= '<tr class="f5">\r';
    $pstrout .= '<td align="center" class="npagecounter" style="height:20px;color:#0000FF">\r'; 

    if ($pg >= 2){
        $pstrout .= '<a href="pg=1" id="Page1Link">&laquo;&nbsp;First</a>&nbsp;\r';
    }

    if (pg >=2){
        $pstrout .= '<a href="pg='.($pg-1).'" id="Page'.($pg-    1).'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;\r';
    }

    if (max_pg > 5){
        $npage_t = $pg + 4;
        $npage_count_diff = $max_pg - $pg;
        if ($npage_count_diff == 0){
            $npage_count_diff2 = 4;
        }elseif ($npage_count_diff == 1){
            $npage_count_diff2 = 3;
        }elseif ($npage_count_diff == 2){
            $npage_count_diff2 = 2;
        }else{
            $npage_count_diff2 = 1;
        }
        if ($npage_t > $max_pg){
            if ($npage_count_diff <= 3){
                for ($ipages=$pg-$npage_count_diff2;$ipages=$max_pg;$ipages++){
                    if($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for ($ipages=$pg;$ipages=$max_pg;$ipages++){
                    if ($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if ($pg == 1){
                for ($ipages=$pg;$ipages=($pg+4);$ipages++){
                    if ($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }elseif ($pg == 2){
                for ($ipages=($pg-1);$ipages=($pg+3);$ipages++){
                    if ($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for ($ipages=($pg-2);$ipages=($pg+2);$ipages++){
                    if ($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        for ($ipages=1;$ipages=$max_pg;$ipages++){
            if ($ipages == $pg){
                $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>&nbsp;';
            }else{
                $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($max_pg > 1){
        if ($pg <> $max_pg){
            $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.($pg+1).'" id="Page'.($pg+1).'Link">Next&nbsp;&raquo;</a>&nbsp;';
        }
    }
    if ($max_pg > 1){
        if ($pg <> $max_pg){
            $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$max_pg.'" id="Page'.$max_pg.'Link">Last&nbsp;&raquo;</a>';
        }
    }

    $pstrout .= '</td>\r';
    $pstrout .= '</tr>\r';
    $pstrout .= '<tr>\r';
    $pstrout .= '</table>\r'; 
    return $pstrout;
}

$current_page = 2;
$total_page = 24;
echo pagination($current_page,$total_page);
?>
```

I probably have one bracket out of place.  Please can you help me resolve this issue, with the infinite loop.

Many thanks!

Comment: When im done are you going to mail me a check?

Comment: At the very top, `if (max_pg > 5)` should be `if ($max_pg > 5)`

Comment: same for `if (pg >=2){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loops are wrong.

Change this:

```
for ($ipages=$pg;$ipages=$max_pg;$ipages++){
```

to this:

```
for ($ipages=$pg;$ipages<=$max_pg;$ipages++){
```

you need to do this for all the for loops and also makes changes according to comments to your question. There might be other errors in the code too but this is a good place to start.

I made some other changes to your code and added it to PHP Fiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/qdt-r7t The logic still does not seem to be working correctly but that page should be a good starting point.

Also, questions like this are better suited for the Code Review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong use of comparison operators, several times, you are using assignment operations

```
for ($ipages=$pg-$npage_count_diff2;$ipages=$max_pg;$ipages++)
```

`$ipages=$max_pg;` should be `$ipages==$max_pg;`

would probably be better with 
`$ipages<=$max_pg;`

as with just == it only stops if it hits $max_pg, there might be an instance where it skips over $max_pg and never hits it.

Answer (score 1):

second loop

```
 }else{
                for ($ipages=$pg;HERE --> $ipages=$max_pg   <---HERE;$ipages++){
                    if ($ipages == $pg){
                        $pstrout .= '<span style="padding:2px 6px" class="fb">'.$ipages.'</span>';
                    }else{
                        $pstrout .= '<a href="?pg='.$ipages.'" id="Page'.$ipages.'Link">'.$ipages.'</a>&nbsp;';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

i added some echo to your code to run a quick test :

```
if ($pg == 1){
    for ($ipages=$pg;$ipages=($pg+4);$ipages++){
        echo "case 0 ".$ipages." ... ";
        [....]
    }
} else if ($pg == 2){
    for ($ipages=($pg-1);$ipages=($pg+3);$ipages++){
        echo "case 1 ".$ipages." ... ";
        [...]
    }
} else {
    for ($ipages=($pg-2);$ipages=($pg+2);$ipages++){
        echo "case 2 ".$ipages." ... ";
        [...]
    }
}
```

i got the following result :

```
case 1 5 ... case 1 5 ... case 1 5 ... case 1 5 ... case 1 5 ... case 1 5 ...
```

You should replace your operators as others mentioned